# Need help with understanding question about Pre images and Images

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$, let $S$ be a subset of $X$, and let $U$ be a subset of $Y$. What, in general, can one say about $f^{-1}(f(S))$ and $S$?

Okay so the problem I'm having with this question is it's very vague, so I'll just right down what I know and let me know if it's "enough" to describe the above.

---

Let's consider the Image of $S$, that is $f(S)$. We know by definition 
$f(S) = \{f(x): x \in S\}$. Let's call this set $C$. Now let's consider the Pre-Image of $C$, $f^{-1}(C)$. There are two cases, $C=U$ or $C \neq U$. If $$C = U$$ then $$f^{-1}(C) = \{x \in S: f(x) \in C\}$$ If $$C \neq U$$ then $$f^{-1}(C) = \{x \in X: f(x) \in C\}$$

---

So this is all I can really come up with; I don't know what I should say about $S$? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is asking whether the two sets are equal; and if not is one a subset of the other.

Comment: @paw88789 Now that I think about it, that's probably it haha, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the elements in $S$, by definition of $C$, have their image in $C$ so they belong to $\;f^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr)$. Thus 
$$S\subseteq f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr).$$